# Can null check cause client side evaluation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd want to ask why query like this is being evaluated on the client side:

```
_context
    .Items
    .Include(x => x.Status)

    .Include(x => x.Orders)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.User)

    .Include(x => x.Orders)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.OrderStatus)

    .Where(x => x.Orders.Any())
    .Where(x => x.Order != null)
    .Where(x => x.Order.User.SomeProperty.ToLower() == user.SomeProperty.ToLower());
```

where user used in `user.SomeProperty.ToLower()` is just Identity user and it isn't null.

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id = { get; protected set; }

    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();

    public Order Order => Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderStatus.Name = "Active");

    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id = { get; protected set; }

    public User User = { get; set; }

    public Status OrderStatus = { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public Guid Id = { get; protected set; }

    public string Name = { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core warnings say that null check is one of the reasons, but I cannot understand why would null check cannot be translated

> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>   The LINQ expression 'where (Property([x].Order, "Id") != null)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>   The LINQ expression 'where ([x].Order.User.SomeProperty==__user_SomeProperty_0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF can not translate query in methods or properties. Move this

```
public Order Order => Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderStatus.Name = "Active");
```

To the actual query

edit. You can use extension methods to reuse queries instead

edit2: Create an extension method

```
public static class FooQueryExtensions
{
   public static IQueryable<FooResult> MyFooQuery(this IQueryable<Foo> source)
   {
      return source.SelectMany(...).Where(...); //basicly do what yuo want
   }
}
```

used like

```
_context.Set<Foo>().MyFooQuery().Where(result => more query);
```

Comment: So, I gotta perform .ToList() before  ``.Where(x => x.Order != null)``?

Comment: Thats one solution but it could be very expensive if you have many items. I would write a extension method that takes the correct IQueryable

Comment: Can I move that Func to one place and use it in both - Orders.cs (``public Order Order => Orders.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OrderStatus.Name = "Active");``) and database Queries? or it's kind of impossible

Comment: Yes, you can move it to an extension method that takes a IQueryable<Something> and returns IQueryable<someresult>

Comment: I meant, using it as property definition ``public Order Order => MyMethodThatReturnsIQueryable();``?